# How to chose Table based on parameterized database name?

Tags: sql

My code takes in a parameter `${ID}$` (string) and based on what ID evaluates to I want to chose a different table to use. Guess I cant use a case inside a FROM statement. Some example code looks like:

```
select *
from ${ID}$_charges.transaction_charge
where execution_date = '2011-03-22'
```

So if `ID` is 'N' then I want to use the transaction_charge table so the statement resolves to `N_charges.transaction_charge`

However if `ID` is 'B' or 'P' then I want to use a different table called conformity_charge and the statement would evaluate to `B_charges.conformity_charge` or `P_charges.conformity_charge`

How can I write this statement?

Comment: MySQL <> Postgres. I removed the conflicting tags, please tag only the one database you are running.

Comment: You can't have a variable table name in pure SQL - this would require *dynamic SQL*. It is probably simpler to build the query string in your application than in the database.

Comment: Where is the code being run, purely in sql, in a stored function/procedure, an external client?

Comment: Its being run purely sql

Comment: This is a bad data model. You should only have a single table with a column `charge_type` or something similar. Then your query gets as simple as `.. from transaction_charge where charge_type = 'B' and execution_date = '...'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a low number of possible tables to target, the closest you can get, apart from dynamic SQL, is:

**NOTE: Depending of the capabilities of your database engine and the size of your tables there might be performance penalties that may or may not matter.**

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (
   SELECT 'N' as TableName, a, b, c
   FROM N_charges.transaction_charge
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'P' as TableName, a, b, c
   FROM P_charges.transaction_charge
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B' as TableName, a, b, c
   FROM B_charges.transaction_charge
) t
WHERE TableName = '${ID}$'

# Another variation
SELECT a, b, c
FROM N_charges.transaction_charge
WHERE 'N' = '${ID}$'
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, c
FROM P_charges.transaction_charge
WHERE 'P' = '${ID}$'
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, c
FROM B_charges.transaction_charge
WHERE 'B' = '${ID}$'
```

Comment: For the first variation I keep getting the following error: 'column "N" does not exist in t' when using ID N for exmaple

Comment: @DanHoward You get the error because using `${ID}$` for the parameter doesn't seem to be the correct syntax. To know what exactly to write I'd need to know what database engine you're using and what language, tool etc. the query is executed from. It would be good if you tagged your question with the database engine you use. It might be as easy as writing `'${ID}$'` but I can't know.

Comment: It was as easy as writing '${ID}$' haha thank you and thanks for the advice. Ill be sure to be more informative in my posts.

Comment: @DanHoward Good to know it was just that. I added the quotes to my answer.